# Maven surfire tests reusefork vs parallel

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing, junit4, applicationcontext

Now I have a complete project and I wanted to parallel the testing in maven.
If I set the parallel option, mine tests fails cause of `DirtiesContexts`. (Even if I annotate the testclasses with `@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`)

I'm not putting the stacktrace here but its failed to load applicationcontext cause he can't register the applicationcontext cause its already there.

If I use reusefork it tests succeeds even without annotating the `DirtiesContext`.

When you use reusefork you will create always new VM for each fork (and that's the reason why it is succesfull).
(see doc here : http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

With parallel you will not do this so normally this would have less resources needed.

So now of to the question :

1. The link of doc says with parallel for TestNG only, but [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Running_tests_in_parallel) they speak of JUnit 4.7 and higher so I'm confused, what's the correct documentation?
2. Is parallel testing better dan reusefork?
3. If its better, how can I fix the `DirtiesContext`?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this blog post might answer some of your questions
http://incodewetrustinc.blogspot.com/2010/01/run-your-junit-tests-concurrently-with.html